# Representation of power series?

Tags: calculus, power-series

[Link to problem](https://i.gyazo.com/ab6dbd67f785c8f4675ccae41cb55506.png)

I got $∑\frac{(3x^2)^{n+1}}{n+1}$ as my series. But the coefficients do not work for the power series. Why?

Comment: Try to learn [$\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that your questions become more clear.  Also, viewers should not have to follow links just to see your question.  Please try to put the problem in the question and the link as an extra source in case we are still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

$$\;|3x^2|<1\iff x^2<\frac13\iff |x|<\frac1{\sqrt3}\;,$$

we get

$$\log(1-3x^2)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(3x^2)^n}n=-3x^2-\frac{9x^4}2-\frac{27x^6}3-\ldots$$

Comment: That is what I have obtained as well. The coefficients that I see here is -3,-9/2,-27/3,... which is supposedly wrong according to the website (webworks).

Comment: I can't say what that site is, but the answer is, as far as I can see, $\;0,0,-3,0,-\frac92\;$

Comment: Can you help explain to me why?

Comment: @John Just check what the coefficients of $\;x^0, x^1,x^2,x^3,x^4,...$ etc. are. That's what they mean with $\;c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3,...$ , since they wrote there $\;\sum c_nx^n\;$ , meaning: as **consecutive** powers of $\;x\;$ , and you have here *only* even powers: $\;(x^2)^n=x^{2n}\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

Using Taylor's theorem:

$$f(x)=f(0)+\frac{f'(0)}1x+\frac{f''(0)}{1\times2}x^2+\frac{f'''(0)}{1\times2\times3}x^3+\dots+\frac{f^{(n)}}{n!}x^n+\dots$$

So, we have

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(1-3x^2)=\frac{2x}{x^2-\frac13}=\frac4{x-\sqrt{\frac13}}-\frac4{x+\sqrt{\frac13}}$$

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\ln(1-3x^2)=\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\frac{d}{dx}\ln(1-3x^2)$$

$$=\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(\frac4{x-\sqrt{\frac13}}-\frac4{x+\sqrt{\frac13}}\right)$$

$$=\frac{4\times(-1)^{n-1}(n-2)!}{\left(x-\sqrt{\frac13}\right)^n}-\frac{4\times(-1)^{n-1}(n-2)!}{\left(x+\sqrt{\frac13}\right)^n}$$

Now all that's left is to consider $x=0$ and $n=3,4,\dots$ and divide them by $n!$

Comment: Iff $f(x)$ is analytic around $x=0$. Here $f(z) = \log(1-3z^2)$ is holomorphic (complex differentiable) on $|z| < 3^{1/2}$ since $f'(z) = \frac{6z^2}{1-3z^2}$, so by [the holomorphic$\implies$analytic theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions) it means $f(z)$ is analytic on $|z| < 3^{1/2}$

Comment: Of course, you can also prove directly that $f'(z)$ is analytic around $z=0$ (so that $f(z)$ is analytic too) without the theorem

Comment: @user1952009 The latter was what I was thinking.

Comment: Then use it. As it is, your answer is wrong.

Comment: @user1952009 How so?

Comment: the geometric series $f'(z) = \frac{6z}{1-3z^2} = 6z\sum_{k=0}^\infty (3z^2)^k$ for $|z| < 3^{-1/2}$. so that $f(z) = \int_0^z f'(s)ds = \ldots$

Comment: @user1952009 I don't think you applied the chain rule correctly.  Anyways, that is a good idea, you should post it as an answer hinting at geometric series

Comment: nobody cares I made a mistake...

Comment: @user1952009 +1 $\color{white}{\text{I feel you man.}}$

Comment: ? I'm trying to teach you something fundamental : prove that $f(z)$ is analytic before using the Taylor theorem (and proving $f(z)$ is analytic without the holomorphic $\implies$ analytic theorem can be quite hard)

Comment: @user1952009 >_> I already know it is holomorphic... why are you trying to tell me this?  Besides, the question-context makes it clear it is at least analytic. (btw, secret message in previous comment)

Comment: Because given your answer it is obvious you don't know very well the difference between $C^\infty$ and analytic (and the OP neither). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function

Comment: @user1952009 Actually, knowing that it can be represented as a power series (given by the question?) means its analytic... and I know there is a difference, like with $e^{-1/x^2}$ I do think.

Comment: Ok, then next time try to make it clear for the OP (if we assume $f(x)$ is analytic then its power series is blabla... otherwise we can prove it is since its derivative is blabla..)

Comment: @user1952009 Sorry, I had just thought the OP was already clear on that.